What are the alternatives to "tags" in IOTA SDK / Node Core API?
We would like to integrate the "tag" feature to mark some of the data on IOTA Tangle. However, this feature is no longer available in IOTA SDK, which we are currently using. Does anyone know if there are any alternatives for "tags" in IOTA Shimmer to mark/tag the data for further use?
Thanks a lot,
Jami

Tags are still there.
You can either use a tagged data payload as payload for your blocks (if they should only contain data and a tag, and no other transaction).
Or you can add a tagged data payload to a transaction payload's payload field, if you want to tag a transaction that also moves funds.
